# How are the "structs" and "mapstructure" struct tags in Hashicorp's Go GCP Common module used?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, struct

The `GcpCredentials` struct in the [`github.com/hashicorp/go-gcp-common`](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-gcp-common) Hashicorp GCP module contains the struct tags `structs` and `mapstructure`. How are these tags used?

This can be seen [in the code here](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-gcp-common/blob/a5bce1544c1db56c62a24c50ca4478a5e75b3e3c/gcputil/credentials.go#L44-L51):

```golang
// GcpCredentials represents a simplified version of the Google Cloud Platform credentials file format.
type GcpCredentials struct {
    ClientEmail  string `json:"client_email" structs:"client_email" mapstructure:"client_email"`
    ClientId     string `json:"client_id" structs:"client_id" mapstructure:"client_id"`
    PrivateKeyId string `json:"private_key_id" structs:"private_key_id" mapstructure:"private_key_id"`
    PrivateKey   string `json:"private_key" structs:"private_key" mapstructure:"private_key"`
    ProjectId    string `json:"project_id" structs:"project_id" mapstructure:"project_id"`
}
```